# how long will it take from airplane just arrived in Geneva airport to the train which is in train station in same building?

Tags: airport-transfer, airport-security, geneva

I will arrive to Geneva airport from Paris, the specified arrival time is 09:05 in the morning. I heard that the airport terminal and train station are in same floor there,
I have to transfer to the train to Interlaken right away and can I make it to the 10:00 train after all the luggage claim and sort of security pat down things?
if that 55 minutes are too much pushing how much time will be the best?

Comment: Duplicate, but to address your specific question: if your flight is one time it should be fine, especially if you arrive from a Schengen area airport, don’t have checked luggage and have already bought your tickets online. Otherwise it might be just a tiny bit short. It’s not so much getting to the train station (that takes 5 minutes after exiting customs), it’s more about the time to exit the plane, get to passport control and wait in line (if applicable), wait for your luggage, and buy your ticket. Of course there’s also the issue of your flight possibly arriving late.

Comment: Would it not be safer to take the train all the way? Paris to Geneva is about three hours (there are other routes from Paris to Interlaken) and given the amount of time you are going to wait in the Paris airport and possible delays in getting out of Geneva it will probably be quicker in elapsed time.

Comment: thanks @jcaron for replying. Yes, my consideration was the time you mentioned takes. ( it’s more about the time to exit the plane, get to passport control and wait in line (if applicable), wait for your luggage, and buy your ticket. Of course there’s also the issue of your flight possibly arriving late.) <-while doing that. I think I'll buy a train ticket in advance and just call it in the air if I can make it through from airplane to train in 55minutes.

Comment: @mdewey thanks pointing out that. I was seraching for the quickest route among all and I'm still not sure but this one is the fastest one I could find. buses takes too long, and trains are similar in price but takes little longer.. the reason I'm in this rushing is that there's some activities I don't want to miss in Jungfrau region and October is low season I don't have much time before they close. sometimes I feel like worst planner

Comment: The train from Paris to Interlaken takes about 5:15. You only need to be at the station, which is in the center of Paris, a short time before departure. In contrast, the train from the Geneva airport to Interlaken alone takes 3:00, plus the hour flight (if it's on time), arriving at the airport a suitable time in advance, getting to the airport (which will be farther than the train station), waiting for luggage, allowing time for the plane->train connection, etc... If you're looking for the quickest route, taking the train all the way likely wins.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know about how efficient baggage claim is in Genève.

However, if your flight is more or less on time, you have more than enough time. Getting the train ticket is no big deal; you can get it at the counter or at a ticket vending machine (if you have a voucher for a pass, you'd have to go to the counter).

If time is tight and you are not alone, you could send someone from your party ahead to get the train tickets.

Finally, if you miss the 10:00 train, don't worry, there is the 11:00 train…

As you come from Paris, you will be within Schengen zone anyway, so there will be no immigration, and what do you think about security (when leaving the airport…).

The suggestion to do the whole trip by train should really be considered…